# What's the query needed to copy data from one table to another two?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I recently changed my database structure and now I want to copy from my old table `Transfers` to the new ones I just created (`Orders` and `Orders_Transfer`):

```
--old table to copy from
-- table 'Transfers'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transfers] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [Memo] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Employee_Id] int  NULL,
    [InventoryFrom_Id] int  NOT NULL,
    [InventoryTo_Id] int  NOT NULL,
);

-- new tables to copy to
-- table 'Orders'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders] (
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] datetime  NOT NULL,
    [Memo] nvarchar(max)  NULL,
    [Employee_Id] int  NULL
);

-- Creating table 'Orders_Transfer'
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders_Transfer] (
    [Id] int  NOT NULL,--foreign key on Orders.Id
    [InventoryFrom_Id] int  NOT NULL,
    [InventoryTo_Id] int  NOT NULL
);
```

I want to iterate through the old `Transfers` table and copy some part of it to `Orders` (Date, Memo, Employee) and the rest to `Orders_Transfer` (InventoryFrom_Id, InventoryTo_Id). The `Id` column in `Orders_Transfer` is also a FK on `Orders.Id` so I want to copy the auto-generated value as well.
I read about the `scope_identity()` function and the `OUTPUT` clause, but I’m a beginner to SQL and can’t put it all together.

I’m using SQL Server 2008

What is the query I need to do this? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an `OldId` column on the `Orders` table to store the old primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] ADD [OldId] INT;
```

Then copy in the old data:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders]
(
[OldId],[Date],[Memo],[EmployeeID]
)
SELECT [Id] AS [OldId],[Date],[Memo],[EmployeeID]
FROM [dbo].[Transfers];
```

Copy the remaining data using the OldId:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders_Transfer] 
(
    [Id],
    [InventoryFrom_Id],
    [InventoryTo_Id]
)
SELECT
O.Id, T.[InventoryFrom_Id], T.[InventoryTo_Id]
FROM [dbo].[Orders] O
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Transfers] T
ON O.[OldId] = T.[Id];
```

And drop the `OldId` column:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Orders] DROP COLUMN [OldId];
```

Comment: this looks good, very crafty, I'll try it right now and if it works I'll mark it as answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

To keep the Id values in sync you are going to need to use IDENTITY_INSERT.

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Orders ON;

/* Insert data into the Orders table */
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Orders]
       ([Id]
       ,[Date]
       ,[Memo]
       ,[Employee_Id])
SELECT Id
     , Date
     , Memo
     , Employee_Id
  FROM Transfers;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Orders OFF;

/* Insert data into the Orders_Transfer table */
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Ordres_Transfer]
           ([Id]
           ,[InventoryFrom_ID]
           ,[InventoryTo_ID]
SELECT Id
     , InventoryFrom_ID
     , InentoryTo_ID
  FROM Transfers;
```

Comment: sorry, I realize it's not clear in my question but the `Orders` table has more data already, it isn't really new, the Id's have to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Insert into newtable select * from oldtable      //if same schema
insert into newtable(col1,col2,col3) select col1,col2,col3 from old table  // for different table schema
```